# Can we have vertical buttons in an Android alert dialog?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

By default, we get two or three buttons that are horizontally aligned in an alert dialog. Is it possible to have them vertically aligned within the alert dialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can use `Dialog.setContentView()` to set the content of a dialog to be an arbitrary layout.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutId);
dialog.show();
```

Make yourself a layout file with a Vertical LinearLayout that has the buttons you want in it and call `setContentView()` on your dialog, passing the name of your layout file.

If you are deadset on `AlertDialog` you can do something similar with `builder.setView()`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutRoot));
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setView(layout);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 6):

There has been a setItems() call which does this since API level 1. No reason to create a custom dialog unless you want to change the look and feel of the items.

```
CharSequence[] items =  {"Foo", "Bar", "FooBar"};
new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
.setTitle("Choose a widget")
.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
     {
         switch(which)
         {
             case FOO:
             // foo case
             break;

             ....
         }
     }
}
.create().show();
```

Comment: One note on this: you can't call setMessage on the alert, if you do you won't see the items.

Comment: Great code. You should mention that it create vertical buttons because I thought  first that this will create horizontal ones.